# Return statement in python with no return value

Tags: python-3.x

My question is, is it ok to use return in python as follows:

```
    def do_something():
        do something
        return
```

I know this function doesn't return anything, but is there any use in putting return at the bottom? I normally do this out of habit, but am new to python.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, care to give an example of when this would be useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example code you posted, no, it doesn't serve any special purpose. An implicit return of `None` will happen regardless once the end of the function is reached.

There are legitimate cases to use a `return` without a value though:

```
def func(n):
  if n >= 0:
    return

  print("N was negative!") 

func(1) #  Doesn't print anything
func(-1) # Prints that N is negative
```

This is a contrived example, but it will only print if `n` is negative since the `return` will cause the function to return and exit. `return` can be used as a control-flow mechanism to prevent the rest of the function from executing. Whether or not it should be used like this though is the source of endless debate, and depends on the use case.

Comment: Ok I gotcha, thanks.